# What is the UK-English Equivalent for "band-aid?"

Tags: british-english, dialects

What is the UK-English equivalent for "band-aid?" That is, the bandage one puts
over cuts and the like?

Comment: The British English word is 'Plaster'.

Comment: Are you referring to the literal consumer product, i.e. an adhesive bandage, or are you referring to the metaphorical sense, i.e. of a stopgap corrective?

Answer (score 10):

The generic name for such products is *adhesive bandage*, more informally *sticking plaster*

[*Band Aid*](http://www.band-aid.com/) is a US proprietary brand.

The equivalent in the UK, and across much of the Anglo world, is [*Elastoplast*](http://www.boots.com/en/Boots-Brands-A-to-Z/Elastoplast/)

Years ago people in Britain used to use the word *Elastoplast* and no doubt many still do. But I sense it has given way to some extent to *sticking plaster*, or just *plaster* as an everyday term - perhaps because *Elastoplast* is a bit of a mouthful. Nonetheless the brand is still dominant.

You may find [this](http://www.wisegeekhealth.com/what-is-sticking-plaster.htm) interesting.

Comment: Just for completeness, is "plaster" in the UK also used in the metaphorical sense of a "stopgap corrective"?

Comment: @Brad Yes. e.g. *Following its forced about-turn on reductions in tax-credits, the UK Government are having to resort to **sticking plaster** to hold together their policy of reducing the cost of welfare by £12 billion.*

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for "plaster" or do you need specific brands?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-Aid

Comment: I guess "plaster" should cover it. ;-)